# Objects: mixture of data and infrastructure?

Tags: object-oriented, architecture

In our code we have some classes that represents business logic. Prior to usage, they are created and populated with two types of inputs:

- business data required for execution (e.g. `name`, `maxValue`...)
- infrastructure references to e.g. database, message bus, http client... etc, anything that is not related to business, but needed for communication with underlaying infrastructure.

We have the following options to separate inputs:

#### /A have everything in constructor:

```
public Foo(String name, DbRef db)
```

I would like to be able to separate somehow these two types of inputs. As number of arguments can be big, I do not want to overload constructor or to make it with huge number of arguments.

#### /B infra in constructor, data via setters

```
public Foo(DbRef db)...
public Foo setName(String name)...
```

This way you can't create an object without passing the infra, but you need to add extra validation if some required argument is not missing (there is no compile-time check for that).

#### /C required data in constructor, infra and optional data via setters

```
public Foo(String name)...
public Foo bind(DbRef dbref)...
public Foo setMaxValue(int maxValue)...
```

This way you must not forget to call `bind`, but at least it is always the same method - and this binding can be done automatically by e.g. proxy, probably, to reduce possible human errors.

I have started with B but now I am leaning towards the C.

How would you architecture this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, I wouldn't couple the business concepts to infrastructure concerns - have a look at "port's and adapters", infrastructure should adapt to the primary/secondary ports of the domain. Databases, in this context, is a secondary port (something that is called by the domain object, rather than something that calls the domain object).

Regarding constructor/property/method injection, consider this:
Is concept 'x' an actual whole 'x' without dependency 'y'?
A customer without a name & id is probably not valid, so dont make it possible to make that (prefer constructor injection). 
Changing data via setters is generally a bad idea IMO, sonce it introduces temporal coupling and the need for all colaborative objects to query state, introducing a lot of other problems.
Method injection is the best way to introduce trancient dependencies, something that can be used and trown away later - i.e. not something that defines the object, but something it needs in order to do something specific.
This could be registration of an observer, persisting to a repository or notification via messaging.

In general, I think it smells mostly like the 'business logic' is polluted by infrastructure concerns, and untill you decouple that, neither A, B or C will have significant advantage. 
Hope that helps

Comment: But I cant, that is the whole point. Business logic _uses_ infrastructure to get/write information during execution - and that is not a uncommon case. For example, one business method may read additional data from database  and process it. Show me the business service method that is not 'polluted' by infrastructure - that is what I would like to see :) I will check "port and adapters", however, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Yea check out ports and adapters. Of course business logic depends on persisted data, and needs to persist data - which of course needs infrastructure... The point is that we don't need to be coupled to something just because we need to use it (inversion of control)

Comment: yes, I am aware of IOC - hence solution C. But in my case, the class is allowed to be strongly coupled to infrastructure. This is not the coupling between business components, cause this objects I am talking about are _commands_ that needs to execute. Ok, will check port and adapters :)

Comment: "ports and adapters" (from heax-pattern),,, adapters are wrappers over ports. This is nothing new, and of course I might have that. Think of `DbRef` as an db adapter. The question still remains.

Comment: I might have gone off track ;)
Then my suggestion is to prefer constructor injection for data, and method injection for methods involved with infrastructure, and don't keep the DbRef instance as class state - to avoid/abstract transactional issues to a service layer

Comment: if we dont keep DbRef as class state, how our business execute method is going to use it? I mean - the adapter, of course. Should we pass it to the method as arguments?

Comment: but this is short lived object, that runs inside one transaction. Storing DbRef adapter is just convenience.

Comment: "Should we pass it to the method as arguments?" - If it's a service, put infrastructure in the constructor - if it's business policies, or calculations, I would probably have immutable data-only types. 
The service would call methods on the business-objects, supplying the information needed throughout the usecase. This makes it easier to make context-specific dependencies (like for example the state of a business flow).

Comment: ... And leaves less refactoring work in the future...
But you end up with more, yet smaller, classes - also easier to unittest

Comment: Example of business service without infrastructure (namespace renamed):
https://gist.github.com/JulianMay/daa5607b13d8a6b9c9b220a14a3d1fb2